# RDMS for C language newbie?

Tags: mysql, sql, c, database

What database should a beginner use in the C language?

Can I use MySQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL, or any other DBMS with a C language binding.

- [SQLite In 5 Minutes Or Less](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html)
- [MySQL C API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c.html)
- [PostgreSQL C API](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/libpq.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you question is "What RDBMS do you recommend for beginner?" I agree that MySQL is not a bad choice. It's easy to install and configure. I think that most RDMS can be accessed from C code now days

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has C bindings, so you could use that; libmysql usually installs the necessary headers and library files. You might also experiment with something like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) if you just want to mess about with a DBMS in C.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, most have C bindings, so would be suitable.  MySQL is open source and has lots of online docs and books in print, so this is a good start.

SQLite has a growing number of fans but I have yet to use it. It would be much easier to setup/install so could be good for learning about tables and SQL.